# Finding singularities of a complex function and the respective residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, singularity

Consider the function,

$$f(z) = \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{z})}{z^2+a^2} \text{ where } a>0$$

I know that this has two simple poles at $z = \pm ia$ and an essential singularity at $z = 0$ because of $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ in the numerator. For $\operatorname{Res}(f,ia)$ and $\operatorname{Res}(f,-ia)$, it is relatively easy to find the these values using

$$a_{-1} = \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} ((z-z_0)f(z))$$

However, I am finding it much more difficult to determine the residue at an essential singularity.  From what I have read, it seems that the easiest way to determine the residue is to explicitly find the Laurent Expansion and then get it from there. Would this be the case for this function as well?

Comment: Actually the easiest way is to use the fact that the sum of all residues of $f$ is $0$.

Comment: How do we know that? I can't seem to find that in any of the reading. Also, I'm finding that $Res(f, -ia) = Res(f, ia) = \frac{sin(\frac{1}{ia})}{2ia}$ and $Res(f, 0) = \frac{1}{a^2}$ which does not add up to zero in this case.

Comment: You have the wrong residue at $0$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598846/what-is-the-residue-of-this-essential-singularity) is a quite similar question.

Comment: Alright, so if I'm not mistaken $\oint_C f(z) dz = Res(f, ia)+Res(f, -ia)+Res(f, 0)$ therefore, if we know two of the residues and can solve the contour integral then we can find the third residue. Is that correct?

Comment: Modulo a factor of $2\pi i$, and the condition that $C$ encloses all three singularities. Take $C$ as $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert = R\}$ for $R > \lvert a\rvert$, and let $R \to +\infty$ to see that the integral is $0$.

Comment: Performing the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_c \frac{f_1(z)}{z-ia} + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_c \frac{f_2(z)}{z+ia}$ where $f_1(z) = \frac{sin(\frac{1}{z})}{2ia}$ and $f_2(z)= \frac{-sin(\frac{1}{z})}{2ia}$ leads to $\frac{sin(\frac{1}{ia})}{ia}$ according to Cauchy's Integral Formula. You said this should be zero though correct? Because currently this implies that $Res(f, 0) = 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did there. The integral can't have a dependency on $z$. Anyway, since the residues at $\pm ia$ are the same, and the sum of all residues is $0$, it follows that $\operatorname{Res}(f;0) = -2\operatorname{Res}(f;ia)$.

Comment: I had just used partial fraction decomposition of $f(z)$ to get it into two separate integrals where there was some function over $z-z_0$ so that I could use $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} = f(z_0)$. Shouldn't this work out as well?

Comment: It would work if $f$ has no singularity inside $C$. But we have the essential singularity at $0$.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For positive numers $a<r<R$, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that

$$\oint_{|z|=r>a}\frac{\sin(1/z)}{z^2+a^2}\,dz=\oint_{|z|=R>r}\frac{\sin(1/z)}{z^2+a^2}\,dz$$

Then, noting that $\left|\sin\left(\frac1{Re^{i\phi}}\right)\right|\le \frac{R}{R-1}$ for $R>\max(1,a)$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{\sin(1/z)}{z^2+a^2}\,dz\right|&=\left|\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{Re^{i\phi}}\right)}{R^2e^{i2\phi}+a^2}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|\\\\
&\le  \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left|\sin\left(\frac1{Re^{i\phi}}\right)\right|}{\left|R^2e^{i2\phi}+a^2\right|}\,R\,d\phi\\\\
&\le \frac{R^2}{(R^2-a^2)(R-1)}\\\\
&\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Hence, the sum of the residues of $\frac{\sin\left(1/z\right)}{z^2+a^2}$ is $0$ and we find that

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{\sin\left(1/z\right)}{z^2+a^2},z=0\right)&=-\text{Res}\left(\frac{\sin\left(1/z\right)}{z^2+a^2},z=ia\right)-\text{Res}\left(\frac{\sin\left(1/z\right)}{z^2+a^2},z=-ia\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sinh(1/a)}{a}
\end{align}$$

Comment: reversing the contour, pretty nice (+1)

Comment: @tired Thank you my friend!  Nice to see you're still around.  How are you?

Comment: thanks i'm pretty fine just way too busy to contibute here on MSE regularly :(. How did it go for you the last time? Everything alright?

Comment: @tired Pleased to hear.  I've been lightly contributing here.  There aren't many interesting integrals or series anymore.

Comment: I have exactly the same feeling..it is pretty sad somehow :(

Comment: Where does the estimate $\left|\sin\left(\frac1{Re^{i\phi}}\right)\right|\le \frac{R}{R-1}$ come from? I think $\cosh\frac1R$ would suit here better.